# CakePhp - measuring execution time seems wrong

Tags: performance, cakephp

Hi i am trying to save execution time in my app with this script:
https://gist.github.com/aiphee/8004486cbd37b3f13efd271b8457cb38

Problem is that debugkit number is always higher, sometimes more than one order.

I verified it with 
`ab -k -c 20  -n 80 https://myserver` 
I know there is some network and nginx regime but the debugkit bothers me, why is the number so different?

Comment: Against what number and with what setup exactly are you comparing this? Does your custom script run in debug mode with debug kit enabled too?

Comment: @ndm I am looking at number at debukit bar, yes it does.